# Android Volley Params

Tags: android, android-volley

In my project, i pass the firstname of a user in a params from the JSONobject request. It would then get the response and fill the textviews. however i cant figure out why my code does not work.I checked my php and it works fine when i put a predefined firstname in it, so i ruled out a web service problem. does it get the response first and then pass the params?  please help

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView Username, Firstname, Lastname, Birthdate, Barangay;

String firstname;
String json_url = "http://localhost/android/getprofileinfo.php";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    Username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usernameprofile);
    Firstname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstnameprofile);
    Lastname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lastnameprofile);
    Birthdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.birthdayprofile);
    Barangay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.barangayprofile);

   final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    firstname = bundle.getString(firstname);





    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, (String) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Username.setText(response.getString("username"));
                        Firstname.setText(response.getString("firstname"));
                        Lastname.setText(response.getString("lastname"));
                        Birthdate.setText(response.getString("birthdate"));
                        Barangay.setText(response.getString("barangay"));
                    }

                    catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        } //end of method onErrorResponse

    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("firstname", firstname);
            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getmInstance(ProfileActivity.this).addTorequestque(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

}

this is the getpropileinfo.php

```
<?php

$firstname =$_POST["firstname"];


define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','mydb');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

$sql = "SELECT username,firstname,lastname,birthdate,barangay FROM users 
WHERE firstname LIKE '".$firstname."'; ";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode(array("username"=>$row['username'], 
"firstname"=>$row['firstname'], 
    "lastname"=>$row['lastname'], "birthdate"=>$row['birthdate'], 
"barangay"=>$row['barangay']));
}
?>
```

Comment: are you using your local web service ?

Comment: yes, iam using a local webserver, and my tablet is connect to my wifi

Comment: have you tried with postman ? print your response also in your `onResponse`

Comment: did you try with `PUT` ?

Comment: share the code for `getprofileinfo.php`

Comment: i have placed the getprofileinfo.php

Comment: @RustyMa i think you are not properly getting the `intent extra`, check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly taking the `getExtras()`, provide the key name which you pass using `putExtra()` from your calling activity, like this

In the calling activity pass intent like

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);   
String strName = "some_name";
i.putExtra("key_username", strName);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in ProfileActivity,

```
final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
firstname = bundle.getString("key_username");
```

Convert to `JsonArrayRequest`

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, (String) null,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {

                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                    .get(0);

                            Username.setText(person.getString("username"));
                            Firstname.setText(person.getString("firstname"));
                            Lastname.setText(person.getString("lastname"));
                            Birthdate.setText(person.getString("birthdate"));
                            Barangay.setText(person.getString("barangay"));



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        } //end of method onErrorResponse

    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("firstname", firstname);
            return params;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Try making a jsonarrayrequest instead of jsonobject request

Comment: JSON array has errors saying  "Error:(55, 65) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int". However my JSON object request never had a problems. i believe theres something wrong with my params. the project doesnt fail, it just doesnt change the textviews

Comment: Thanks for answering @Navneet

Comment: your answer is useful. :) i got something from it. but i tried changing it to string request too, and it worked.

Comment: @RustyMa what was the **error**, can you specify(logcat)

Answer (score 0):

May be its issue with your localhost, Go through Genymotion is using your PC IP address. to get your IP address go to:

start -> cmd -> ipconfig
then search for IPv4, copy the IP and paste it in your URL. It should looks like the following:

String YourURL = "http://192.168.0.106:8888/android/getprofileinfo.php";

Hope this works too for you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the method parameters, remove the string casting for the json object.

`null` instead of `(String) null`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JSONRequest to a StringRequest.